# golang progress hanging when reading data from channel

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I have to write a rabbitmq reconnector,and this is what I refrence to:
https://gist.github.com/svcavallar/be2d40953eaf27842cba2d46de9c1fb1

But when I read data from channel `rabbitCloseError`, my progress hang on... i have no idea whats wrong.

Here belows my codes:

```

```
    logger.Infof("Starting message listenner...")
    var rabbitErr *amqp.Error
    var ch *amqp.Channel

    // setup a reconnector
    for {
            rabbitErr = <-rabbitCloseError // hanging here!!
            if rabbitErr != nil {
                logger.Infof("Reconnecting")
                _ = l.rabbitClient.InitConn()
            }
            if ch == nil {
                logger.Infof("Creating channel")

                ch, _ = l.rabbitClient.RabbitmqConn.Channel()
                reportQ, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
                    "filereport", // name
                    true,         // durable
                    false,        // delete when unused
                    false,        // exclusive
                    false,        // no-wait
                    l.rabbitClient.QArguments, // arguments
                )
                if err != nil {
                    logger.Errorf("Declare queue report failed, error: %+v", err)
                }
                // set prefetch one
                _ = ch.Qos(1, 0, false)
                msgs, err := ch.Consume(
                    reportQ.Name, // queue
                    "",           // consumer
                    false,        // auto-ack
                    false,        // exclusive
                    false,        // no-local
                    false,        // no-wait
                    nil,          // args
                )
                if err != nil {
                    logger.Errorf("Decare consumer failed, error: %+v", err)
                }
                go l.ConsumeMsgs(msgs)
            }
    }
}
```

```

Can anyone help me about this? thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise no one can tell you what is wrong exactly. Receiving from a channel blocks until there is data to be received. This is explained in [the tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2).

Comment: You need to wait for data from channel in separate goroutine. I believe you want to reconnect to RabbitMQ if connection was lost - in this case you can follow this post https://ninefinity.org/post/ensuring-rabbitmq-connection-in-golang/

Comment: You also should check errors rather than discarding them.

Comment: Who sends messages to the channel `rabbitCloseError`? May be the problem on that side?

Comment: rabbitmq connection has method `notifyClose`, i did it as official doc says.@EugeneLisitsky

Comment: @Peter thanks for you help.yeah i should put more clear codes here.But i have a question now: what will happen if I put a channel reader into a for loop?will the code hang if the channel is empty?

Comment: @Peter @RidgeA @EugeneLisitsky, Finally i made it! thanks!
i didn't put my listener into a separate goroutine, and not define `rabbitCloseError `